# Stuck at Homogeneos Differential Equation example

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I'm stuck on a problem:  $$(x^2 + y^2)\,dy + 2y^2\, dx = 0$$

Here is the part I've solved so far:

[image]

Can you help me with the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With constants $A$, $B$ and $C$ let
$$\frac{u^2+1}{u(u^2+2u+1)}=\frac{A}{u}+\frac{B}{u+1}+\frac{C}{(u+1)^2}$$
so $A=1$, $B=0$ and $C=-2$
$$\frac{u^2+1}{u(u^2+2u+1)}=\frac{1}{u}+\frac{-2}{(u+1)^2}$$
and
$$-\int\frac{1}{u}+\frac{-2}{(u+1)^2}=\int\frac{1}{x}dx$$
$$-\ln u-2\frac{1}{u+1}=\ln x+C$$
after simplify, the **general** solution is
$$\color{blue}{\boxed{\ln y+\frac{2x}{x+y}=C}}$$

Comment: Sorry i was solving with your way and did you mean at your first eq: c/(u+1)^2 ? if so does it change the rest of the answer ?

Comment: @onurcevik check the solution.!

Comment: Oh. I arleady simplified in your way and .Solution is correct only difference is the answer on my book is y=c.e^(-2x/(x+y)). Which is not a important deal since its probably another simplifying. Thanks for your help

Comment: They are the same. Take $\frac{2x}{x+y}$ to RH and take exponential from two sides.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: the rest part of the integral is $$\\ \int { \frac { { u }^{ 2 }+2u+1-2u }{ u{ \left( u+1 \right)  }^{ 2 } } du } =\int { \frac { { \left( u+1 \right)  }^{ 2 }-2u }{ u{ \left( u+1 \right)  }^{ 2 } } du= } \int { \frac { du }{ u } -2\int { \frac { du }{ { \left( u+1 \right)  }^{ 2 } }  }  } =\\ =\int { \frac { du }{ u } -2\int { \frac { d\left( u+1 \right)  }{ { \left( u+1 \right)  }^{ 2 } }  }  } =\ln { u+\frac { 2 }{ u+1 }  } $$